# Javascript get JSON into arrays, combine and use elsewhere

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js

I'm currently a bit stuck trying to combine two arrays (one of dates, one of times).

I've written a PHP script to pass out JSON from an SQL table I have containing the data, but I'm struggling to turn the two arrays into a single datetime array in JavaScript.

The JSON is coming out as:

```
{
  "dates": [
    "2016-03-13",
    "2016-03-13",
    "2016-03-14",
    "2016-03-14"
  ],
  "times": [
    "16:41:13",
    "17:36:57",
    "08:53:02",
    "21:53:11"
  ]
}
```

So far I'm using this to collect the data, though I'm really not sure where to go from there (or if what I'm getting is even an array?):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var API_URL = "php_script.php";

    $.getJSON(API_URL, function(data) {
        var dates = data.dates;
        var times = data.times;
        console.log(dates + " " + times);
    });

});
```

The output of which is:

```
2016-03-13,2016-03-13,2016-03-14,2016-03-14,16:41:13,17:36:57,08:53:02,21:53:11
```

I'd prefer:

```
[2016-03-13 16:41:13,2016-03-13 17:36:57,2016-03-14 08:53:02,2016-03-14 21:53:11]
```

To be passed out as an array which I can then use with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

The dates and times will be used for the X axis and the time between them for the Y axis, so it would be useful to be able to complete some kind of datetime math on the data, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to manually mix them together.... The gist is to manually splice the strings together and then use `Date.parse()` to make the date objects.

```
var dates = [
"2016-03-13",
"2016-03-13",
"2016-03-14",
"2016-03-14",
];

var times = [
"16:41:13",
"17:36:57",
"08:53:02",
"21:53:11",
];

var both = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    both.push(new Date(Date.parse(dates[i] + " " + times[i])));
}

console.log("%j",both);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is easy if you use a library like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/). In this case you would want [`_.zip`](https://lodash.com/docs#zip)

```
var dates = data.dates;
var times = data.times;

var zipped = _.zip(dates, times);
var text = _.reduce(zipped, function(aggregate, item) { return ',' + item[0] + ' ' + item[1]; });
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try splitting the dates and times with `,` and concat each of them by using loop

```js
var data = {
  "dates": [
    "2016-03-13",
    "2016-03-13",
    "2016-03-14",
    "2016-03-14"
  ],
  "times": [
    "16:41:13",
    "17:36:57",
    "08:53:02",
    "21:53:11"
  ]
}

var datetimes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.dates.length; i++) {
  datetimes.push(data.dates[i] + ' ' + data.times[i]);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(datetimes, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: This assumes that what I'm getting as dates and times are strings? 
Would I be able to have this as some kind of array to use elsewhere?

Comment: sorry,just saw your update.. if you have output as array,they you dont have to split.just uset the loop

Comment: @LADransfield did it helped you?